# How to make zsh's REPORTTIME work? (time for long-running commands)

Tags: zsh

This is my .zshrc:

`export REPORTTIME=3`

When I run `sleep 4` it doesn't output anything.
If I change to `REPORTTIME=blablabla` (or anything non-sensical) it doesn't raise an error and starts behaving as `REPORTTIME=0`, i.e. returning the time taken for everything.

Interestingly, if I try `REPORTTIME=3s` I get the following message:

`` zsh: bad math expression: operator expected at `s'
sleep 4  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 4.004 total ``

So I get the error and still the output.

I tried `RERPORTTIME="3"` and even `REPORTTIME=1+2`. None of these work.

Also, if I run `python -c "import time; time.sleep(4)"` I get the same results (so the problem is not with `sleep`).

Of course, I tried other values too (other than 3).

I'm running MacOS with iterm2 and zsh is my default shell.

Comment: I think the problem is just that `sleep` doesn't really "take" time. Try a different long running process. I reproduced it, `sleep` doesn't report, but `du -s /somereasonablesizedfolder/*` does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set it explicitly to a non-negative integer representing seconds; i.e.

```
% REPORTTIME=3
```

Setting to other non-negative values does not work on my Zsh v5.4.2
either.  Running something like a system update (e.g., `yaourt`) then
acts as if I had put `time` on the front of it.  Pretty slick!

So you need a command that eats some user/system time; `sleep` does
not.  Although total elapsed is long enough, user and system time is
not:

```
% time sleep 3
sleep 3  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 3.002 total
```

Also, no need to `export` this since it's directly used by Zsh.

You can undo/turn off this behavior with:

```
% unset REPORTTIME
```

---

Docs on `REPORTTIME` from `man zshparam`:

> If  nonnegative,  commands  whose  combined user and system execution times (measured in seconds) are greater than this value have timing statistics printed for them.  Output is suppressed for commands executed within the line editor,  including  completion; commands explicitly marked with the time keyword still cause the summary to be printed in this case.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know `REPORTTIME` only counted user/system time, not wall clock time.
BTW, apparently `time.sleep` from python also doesn't count, although it happens inside a python job.
This works: `python -c "import numpy as np; from scipy.linalg import lu; lu(np.random.rand(10000,10000))"`